# Magento2: Cart events

Tags: magento2, event-observer

What are the best events to observe? When

1. A cart is **created**
2. **Updates** a cart
3. A cart is **deleted**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Below Are the list of Events for cart :**

1. checkout_cart_add_product_complete
2. checkout_cart_update_item_complete
3. checkout_cart_product_add_after
4. checkout_cart_update_items_before
5. checkout_cart_update_items_after
6. checkout_cart_save_before
7. checkout_cart_save_after
8. checkout_cart_product_update_after

**For Use of each refer this url -** https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento-2.1-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

Comment: How would you control if the cart was deleted by the user?

Comment: Is there a event for when the cart loads?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need one of these:

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
checkout_cart_update_items_before
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_save_before
checkout_cart_save_after
checkout_cart_product_update_after
```

Have a look at this.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: what is the difference between checkout_cart_product_update_after and checkout_cart_update_items_after?

Comment: `checkout_cart_product_update_after` dispatched inside updateItem(params) method, `checkout_cart_update_items_after` dispatched inside updateItems($data) method. One for single item, one for bulk items in cart.

Comment: is there any event for cart viewed?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Magento 2.3.3 or newer you should check sales_quote events.

For example sales_quote_remove_item when you want to observe the delete action on cart